# what is the equation of ellipse with two points of its large diameter?

Tags: ellipse

I want to get the equation of an ellipse by having two ends of its large diameter. These two points can form the ellipse in any place on the plain with any orientation. I think it is possible to have its small diameter if we have the equation of its large diameter. For example, we say the length of small diameter is half of length of large diameter.

I know the standard equation for ellipse that is centered on point `(0,0)` is `x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1`. But this is the simplest version. My ellipse can be centered at any point with any orientation.

Is it possible to have the equation with this information?
What can the equation be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing two endpoints of a major axis is not enough to make an ellipse equation.
Because an ellipse with one fixed axis can have any eccentricity between 0 and 1.

You can find a brief explanation at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239787/can-an-ellipse-with-fixed-semi-axis-have-different-values-of-eccentricity

So when you get enough information about your ellipse, you can build analytical equation according to formulas here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse